# persist null in JPA Many to one mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using hibernate JPA for my application. I have two entities orders and invoice. orders has a many to one mapping with invoice class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ORDERS",schema ="AMZ")
public class Orders {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "pk_sequence", sequenceName = "ORDERS_SEQ", schema = "AMZ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pk_sequence")
    @Column(name = "ORDERS_ID")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "INVOICE_ID", referencedColumnName = "INVOICE_ID")
    private Invoice invoice;

    //getters and setters 


@Entity
@Table(name="INVOICE",schema ="AMZ")
public class Invoice {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "pk_sequence", sequenceName = "INVOICE_SEQ", schema = "AMZ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pk_sequence")
    @Column(name = "INVOICE_ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "INVOICE_NUMBER")
    private String invoiceNumber;


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "invoice")
private Set<Orders> Orders= new HashSet<Orders>(0);
    //getters & setters
```

When I persist the orders some times I will have the invoice available in invoice table, some times it will be null.

I am receiving Following Error

```
 org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance -
 save the transient instance before flushing : com.domain.Orders.invoice -> 
 com.domain.Invoice; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
 org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance -
 save the transient instance before flushing : 
 com.domain.Orders.invoice -> com.domain.Invoice
```

How to persist null values when there is a many to one mapping?

Comment: Well, set order.invoice to null. What's the concrete problem?

Comment: I am receiving the error TransientPropertyValueException